# R returning output of an apply function in tabular format rather then a vector

Tags: r, vector, data.table, data-cleaning

I have created a function to be used in the apply function and works fine. I am expecting it to return a vector however the output is in tabular format. Here is a toy example to show what I mean.

```
library(data.table)
test_case <- data.frame(channel = 240, time = "2017-02-14")
test_case$channel_list <- list(c("c505", "c240", "c506"))

test_power <- data.frame(channel = c(240,505,506,509), 
                         time = c("2017-02-14", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15"),
                         count = c(25,26,45,50))

setDT(test_case)
setDT(test_power)

countList2 <- function(x, dataset, valley){
  closeDetails <- dataset[channel %in% gsub("c", "", x$channel_list)
                          & time == x$time]
  sourceCount <- dataset[channel == x$channel & time == x$time]$count

  countMin <- as.numeric(sourceCount) * (1 - valley)
  countMax <- as.numeric(sourceCount) * (1 + valley)

  output <- closeDetails[(count >= countMin) & (count <= countMax)]$channel

  print(output)

  return(output)
}

apply(test_case, MARGIN=1, FUN = countList2, valley = 0.2, dataset = test_power)
```

The print in the apply returns:

```
[1] 240 505
```

The apply returns

```
      [,1]
[1,]  240
[2,]  505
```

For ease here is the R-Fiddle [link](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=ty1hObUD)

Comment: Why don't you just wrap your `apply` function into `as.vector()`? The reason apply returns a 2x1 matrix is that you are applying your function by row.

Comment: Not exactly, in the toy example there is a single row which has a list of values. Hence, should return a single vector. When I print in the apply function I get the expected result. The issue is when I return that output

Comment: `test_case` is not a matrix, so don't use `apply` on it... Also, fwiw, if you're doing regex stuff as part of your analysis, your code will be slow and your data is probably arranged wrong; if you're interested, hadley's tidy data paper on that subject might be of interest: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10

Comment: as.vector() seems to have solved the issue but @Frank I definitely need a better organization of the data and treat my dataset just like a database which does not have lists in a row. Thanks for the paper.